# Responsive Image inside a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Well, i have a `div` with `50% width` and `200px` height, there is an image inside this div that i want to make it responsive in all resolution. if i put this image on div's background image and give it `background-size: cover` and responsive output exactly similar what i want. but the problem is i can't to put this image on background image, and should be a `<img/>` element.

[image]

so i made a example on **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4njw64s0/)** to clear my question.

after run this example please change preview section width to see responsive output. ok, top image has a `<img/>` inside that div, bottom image is background image. i want exactly **responsive output** of bottom div that made with `background-image`, in other hand the question is: how can make an image responsive like `background-size: cover` in a div.

```css
#DivWithImg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#DivWithImg img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#DivWithBGImg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red url('http://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/scalefit_600_noupscale/56328113190000a600b9540d.jpeg');
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Div With Image -->

<div id="DivWithImg">
<img src="http://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/scalefit_600_noupscale/56328113190000a600b9540d.jpeg"/>
</div>
<br>
<!-- Div With Background Image -->

<div id="DivWithBGImg">
</div>
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: just make `height: auto`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can make the height `auto` for the image, it should resize accordingly. Or you can just omit the height property, it's set to auto by default if you don't give it a value

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/4njw64s0/1/

update:

you can set a `min-height/width` so the image can do what you want. basically set the minimum height to 100% so it never get smaller height-wise. and then set the min-width to the width of the actual image, so it doesn't ever get smaller than that.

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/4njw64s0/4/

Comment: Did you try it on small resolution? no it's not working, please change width of preview section smaller.I tried `height: auto` before but i don't want this.

Comment: Yes, that is really what i want. `min-height: 200px` for `img` . Thanks for your help.

Comment: @jiff I don't think you should set the `min-height to 200px`, you should keep it at `100%`. this way, if you update your `container height` in the future, you don't have to worry about updating the `min-height` of the image too

Comment: Oh you right, but container always is `200px` but i'm agree with you, `min-height: 100%` is better and right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this with absolute positioning too, to make it behave more like cover. An example **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3L9pLubn/)**

Position absolute with left: 0 and right: 0 with margin: auto centres the image horizontally. Setting the container's overflow to hidden means that it will not expand past the edges of the container.

Fiddle code;

```
<div class="container">
      <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" alt="">
</div>
.container{
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.container img{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; left: 0;
  margin: auto
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work because the image doesn't get bigger when the container gets bigger. I didn't down vote you by the way

Comment: Fair point. Also, I don't mind being downvoted, if the answer is useless - encourages better answers.